# Generate Responsive Search Ads (RSA) variations

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, combinations

A responsive search ad (RSA) mixes up to 15 headlines and 4 descriptions to generate ad units with the possible combinations:

- 2 headlines + 1 descriptions
- 2 headlines + 2 descriptions
- 3 headlines + 1 descriptions
- 3 headlines + 2 descriptions

I'm looking to see if there is a way to have a loop cycle through the headline and description arrays and generate these ad combinations.

Something like?

```
var headlines = ['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5'];
var descriptions = ['d1','d2','d3','d4'];

\\loop code, return for each variation {
headline[0] + " - " + headline[1] + "<br />";
description[0]
};
```

Comment: How are you defining the space of "variations"?

Comment: The ads can be "h1 + h4", "h5 + h2", "h3 + h1", "h1 + h3". Not sure how to define this, but basically every combination of headlines, and every combination of descriptions, combined.

Comment: Maybe the right word here is permutations - not variations.